# How to open keyboard automatically when a dialog opens

Tags: android

I am trying to create a dialog with 2 `EditText` views where one will get the focus and opens up the keyboard automatically. However, I can't seem to get it to work. Below shows my code:

```
public class ItemDetailsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
public ItemDetailsDialogFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Using the builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder detailsInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    detailsInput.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_item_details, null))
    // Add action buttons
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.details_ok_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // TODO
                // Save the details into a map
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.details_cancel_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                ItemDetailsDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
            }
        });
    return detailsInput.create();
}
```

And here is my xml file:

```
<EditText
    style="@style/details_text"
    android:id="@+id/details_desc_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<EditText
    style="@style/details_text"
    android:id="@+id/details_price_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```

If I tried to add this line of code in:  `detailsInput.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);`

I get an error stating

> cannot resolve getWindow() method

I also tried using this [suggestion](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application) and it works. However, I do not want to re-write that entire block of code everytime I need that dialog. Instead, I am trying to create a class so I could create an object with the class. I am new to android development so any help would be greatly appreciated!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to have focus on one EditText you can do it in 2 ways:

- calling `mEditText.requestFocus();` in the `onCreate` method
- adding `<requestFocus />` in your layout file.

for example if you want focus on your first EditText (and keyboard automatically opened) your xml should be like that:

```
<EditText
    style="@style/details_text"
    android:id="@+id/details_desc_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <requestFocus />    <!-- here's the trick -->
</EditText>

<EditText
    style="@style/details_text"
    android:id="@+id/details_price_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```

Comment: For me, works for EditText hosted by Activity but not if it is hosted by a Dialog.